# Filter enqueued styles and scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am looking for a way to reorganize the scripts/styles queue in WP.

I am well aware of the fact altering the queue may have undesired effects, but in this case there are solid reasons for doing it and I will be keeping the situation under control.

I did not find a native WP filter to get that done.

I need to be able to iterate over the queued items before they are printed and reorganize them based on their type (CSS or Javascript). I still want to keep them differenciated between load in head and load in footer.

How may I achieve that? I thought about creating a function that prints the styles but caches the content via PHP Output Buffer and then parsing it with PHP Dom Document.

But... there has to be a less hacky way. Any suggestions?

Comment: If they've been added properly, you can unenqueue them all, then re-enqueue in your preferred order, with a custom plugin. If they haven't been enqueued, life will be more hacky.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @WebElaine - I dislike that approach, it's not much different than unenqueue them all and just hardcoding them into my theme.

Comment: Register them and then you can enqueue them anytime, anywhere and maybe in any order.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @shanebp - But that won't allow me to control what plugins do.